# Symfony custom routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm using routing with annotations in my symfony2 project and i need to implement new feature. I need to generate page depends on current city. City is passed in some actions like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Route("/{name}"
*/
```

And I need some custom requirements for the city parameter. I want to match this route only if passed city is contained in some dynamic array loaded from database, in other case It shoud go to the next route, without throwing an exception.

I tried to use requirements, but not figured out how to pass object into that. With expressions the same problem, i need to pass my service into it but don't know how.

Comment: What is the problem with checking if the city exists inside a controller action?

Comment: The problem here, that i can't continue route checking from action if the city not exists.

Comment: And what if you redirect it manually to the next route?

Comment: And there will be redirect loop, /{name} route will be matched again.

Comment: Is the other action in the same controller as where this action resides? If that is the case, why don't you just call the other action?

Comment: Create Listener.
In listener regenerate route for existing cities and if not exists than redirect to next city. write you logic in listener to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the annotation param converter.

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

```
/**
 * @Route("/city/{name}")
 * @ParamConverter("city", class="AppBundle:City", options={"entity_manager" = "foo"})
 */
public function showAction(City $city)
{
}
```

Else, I guess you can do it yourself in your controller.

But please, note that using 2 routs for the same controller action isn't a real good practise.

And as stated in some comment, you should be able to deal with this kind of verification inside your controller, then redirect where it's needed